# Jenkins declarative pipeline lock name with variable

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a declarative Jenkins Pipeline with a lock, e. g.

```
pipeline {
    environment {
        BRANCH = 'master'
    }
    agent any
    stages{
        stage('stage') {
            options {
                lock(resource: "lock-${env.BRANCH}")
            }
            steps {
                echo "Something"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I execute the pipeline, in the log it says

```
[Pipeline] lock
Trying to acquire lock on [lock-null]
Lock acquired on [lock-null]
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
master
[Pipeline] }
Lock released on resource [lock-null]
```

The environment variable seems to be not set when the lock-name is evaluated, but when the echo argument is evaluated, it is set correctly.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46697480/7677308) to a somewhat related question gave the hint to use a lazily evaluated GString instead of a normal GString. Trying this:

```
pipeline {
    environment {
        BRANCH = 'master'
    }
    agent any
    stages{
        stage('stage') {
            options {
                lock(resource: "lock-${->env.BRANCH}" as String)
            }
            steps {
                echo "${->env.BRANCH}" as String
            }
        }
    }
}
```

gives me the following log messages

```
[Pipeline] lock
Trying to acquire lock on [[no resource/label specified - probably a bug]]
Lock acquired on [[no resource/label specified - probably a bug]]
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
master
[Pipeline] }
Lock released on resource [[no resource/label specified - probably a bug]]
```

So, it looks like the variable can't be resolved correctly.

The problem I want to solve is, creating a multibranch-pipeline which has a lock on a stage. But when the lock has a name, which is not dependend on the branchname, only one branch of the pipeline can run in parallel in this stage.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I managed to solve it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69521882/lockable-resource-plugin-jenkinsfile-dynamic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just use `lock` as a `step` instead of an `option`:

```
pipeline {
    environment {
        BRANCH = 'master'
    }
    agent any
    stages{
        stage('stage') {
            steps {
                lock("lock-${env.BRANCH}" as String) {
                    echo "${env.BRANCH}" as String
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As within `steps` the variable `env.BRANCH` is set, this should work.

Also see [documentation for `lock` step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/lockable-resources/#-lock-%20lock%20shared%20resource).

Answer (score 4):

I recently ran into this myself. `${env}` is not accessible in the `options` block, but `${currentBuild}` is. So what I did was first was `println("$currentBuild")` and get the name of the class. From that, I googled the Java source code docs and followed the functions until I got what I needed.

In my case, I wanted the `${env.NODE_NAME}` and I ended up with `${currentBuild.getRawBuild().getExecutor().getOwner().getDisplayName()}`

Comment: getRawBuild() is a privileged operation. Still, it's good to know that the node name is available at the stage/options level. The lack of a non-privileged interface must be a code shortcoming, not a fundamental limitation.