# Lockable Resource Plugin Jenkinsfile -> Dynamic

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

This is a declarative Jenkins-Pipeline.

With the Lockable Resources Plugin (https://plugins.jenkins.io/lockable-resources/) I want to lock multiple stages dynamically, depending on the environment which was choosed by the user in the parameters section. This is how I wanted this to be done:

```
    pipeline {
    parameters {
        choice choices: ['---', 'prod', 'test'], description: 'Environment', name: 'environment'
    }
    stage('MY_APPLICATION') {
        options{
            lock('resource': "${params.environment}")
        }
        stages {
            stage('TEST') {
                when { expression { "${params.environment}" == 'prod' } }
                steps { ... }
            }
            stage('PROD') {
                when { expression { "${params.environment}" == 'test' } }
                steps { ... }
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

But I have no access to the params in the options block, it always uses the default value. Does anyone have a idea how to lock resources dynamically depending on environment variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it like that:

In the options block, there is the $currentBuild variable available and that way it is possible to lock the resource dynamically:

```
pipeline {
 parameters {
     choice choices: ['---', 'prod', 'test'], description: 'Environment', name: 'environment'
 }
 stage('MY_APPLICATION') {
     options{
         lock('resource': "${currentBuild.getRawBuild().getEnvironment(TaskListener.NULL).environment}")
     }
     stages {
         stage('TEST') {
             when { expression { "${params.environment}" == 'prod' } }
             steps { ... }
         }
         stage('PROD') {
             when { expression { "${params.environment}" == 'test' } }
             steps { ... }
         }
     }
 }
}
```