# Is there a way to use runtime env variable in Jenkins stage lock option?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Found a solution, please look at the end of the post

I'm having trouble setting up a lock on a stage on my Jenkins declarative pipeline.
I want to use an env variable in the lock that I know only at runtime (set by a previous stage).
If I just use ${env.myvar} in the lock name it show "null".

Here is what I've done so far (I tried to simplify the pipeline as much as possible since it is huge but I kept the meaningful parts):

```
import hudson.console.*

pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Init') {
            stages{
                stage('init_1') {
                    steps {
                        script {
                          env.MYVAR = "value"
                        }
                    }
                }
                stage('init_2') {
                    steps {
                        print("${env.MYVAR}")
                    }
                   // other init stuff
                }
            }
        }

        stage('run') {
            agent any

            options {
                lock resource: "${env.MYVAR}"
            }

            stages {
                stage('actually do stuff') {
                    steps {
                        print("${env.MYVAR}")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output of this script is:

```
10:30:47  [Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
10:30:47  [Pipeline] stage
10:30:47  [Pipeline] { (Init)
10:30:47  [Pipeline] stage
10:30:47  [Pipeline] { (init_1)
10:30:47  [Pipeline] script
10:30:47  [Pipeline] {
10:30:47  [Pipeline] }
10:30:47  [Pipeline] // script
10:30:47  [Pipeline] }
10:30:47  [Pipeline] // stage
10:30:47  [Pipeline] stage
10:30:47  [Pipeline] { (init_2)
10:30:47  [Pipeline] echo
10:30:47  value
10:30:47  [Pipeline] }
10:30:47  [Pipeline] // stage
10:30:47  [Pipeline] }
10:30:47  [Pipeline] // stage
10:30:47  [Pipeline] stage
10:30:47  [Pipeline] { (run)
10:30:47  [Pipeline] lock
10:30:47  Trying to acquire lock on [null]
10:30:47  Resource [null] did not exist. Created.
10:30:47  Lock acquired on [null]
10:30:47  [Pipeline] {
10:30:48  [Pipeline] node
10:30:48  Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Pipeline for tests
10:30:48  [Pipeline] {
10:30:48  [Pipeline] stage
10:30:48  [Pipeline] { (actually do stuff)
10:30:48  [Pipeline] echo
10:30:48  value
10:30:48  [Pipeline] }
10:30:48  [Pipeline] // stage
10:30:48  [Pipeline] }
10:30:48  [Pipeline] // node
10:30:48  [Pipeline] }
10:30:48  Lock released on resource [null]
10:30:48  [Pipeline] // lock
10:30:48  [Pipeline] }
10:30:48  [Pipeline] // stage
10:30:48  [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
10:30:48  Finished: SUCCESS
```

SOLUTION FOUND:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49132694/23337672

In my case, it look like that:

```
import hudson.console.*

node {
    stage('init_1') {
        script {
            env.MYVAR = "value"
        }
    }
}

pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Init') {
            stages{
                stage('init_2') {
                    steps {
                        print("${env.MYVAR}")
                    }
                   // other init stuff
                }
            }
        }
        stage('run') {
            agent any

            options {
                lock(resource: "${env.MYVAR}")
            }

            stages {
                stage('actually do stuff') {
                    steps {
                        print("${env.MYVAR}")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a couple of side notes - it's not a scripted pipeline, it's a declarative one, and Jenkins and plugin versions are not sensitive information so you're free to post them.

Comment: I can't spot any issues with your example pipeline except that environment variables are typically uppercase and Jenkins could mess with it in some cases. But... could you add something like `println env.my_var` to `init_2` and `actually do stuff` stages and post the output? It shouldn't be that, but I have a slight suspicion that the environment variables might not survive between the stages run on different agents.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help, I updated the original post with the output of the pipeline. Like you can see, the content env.myvar shows everywhere except on the lock.
I also tried with full caps vars, no luck :'(

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I was incorrect and using a Groovy variable will not work either.

The only thing that worked for me was using `lock()` as a step instead of an option, as suggested on [Jenkins declarative pipeline lock name with variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52314709/jenkins-declarative-pipeline-lock-name-with-variable). This works with both environment and Groovy variables (and by the way you don't need quotes there):

```java
// Jenkinsfile

def myvar

pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Init') {
            stages{
                stage('init_1') {
                    steps {
                        script {
                            myvar = "value"
                        }
                    }
                }
                stage('init_2') {
                    steps {
                        print("${myvar}")
                    }
                   // other init stuff
                }
            }
        }

        stage('run') {
            agent any
            stages {
                stage('actually do stuff') {
                    steps {
                        lock(resource: myvar) {
                            print("${myvar}")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer
Did it work on your side ? I just tried and it still shows "null"

Comment: @Coco you're right. My initial suggestion was more theoretical. Then I double checked and ran into the same issue as you did. I've updated my answer with a working solution.