# Jenkins kubernetes-plugin not understanding env variable in scripted pipeline

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, kubernetes-jenkins-plugin

Jenkins version **2.235.2**

kubernetes-plugin version **1.26.4**

I'm trying to parametrize the yamlFile used as pod template with a env variable based on the branch I'm building. What I have right now is:

```
pipeline {
  environment {
    MASTER_BRANCH = "origin/dev"
    BUILD_POD = "${env.GIT_BRANCH == env.MASTER_BRANCH ? 'jenkins/build-pod-prod.yaml' : 'jenkins/build-pod.yaml' }"
  }
  agent {
    kubernetes {
      idleMinutes 3
      yamlFile env.BUILD_POD
      defaultContainer 'docker'
    }
  }
}
```

But that is taking a default template with just the jnlp container. I've tried also putting:

```
yamlFile env.BUILD_POD
yamlFile "${env.BUILD_POD}"
yamlFile "${BUILD_POD}"
yamlFile "$BUILD_POD"
yamlFile $BUILD_POD
```

But none of that worked. I don't know if it's some misunderstanding from my side or a bug.

I tried also to do the pipeline as a scripted one, which seems like more versatile, but I cannot now neither how to accomplish what I need.

Thanks all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work since your environment variable `BUILD_POD` is not populated when `Jenkins` is configuring `agent {...}` block.
This lead to situation when variable is set as `null` or some empty string and `Jenkins` is using default `jnlp` container.

What you need to do is to set this variable earlier but it is possible only on `master` node.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46630168/in-a-declarative-jenkins-pipeline-can-i-set-the-agent-label-dynamically) should work.